# how to add preview of next and previous slide on hover of Owl Carousel(v1.3.3) navigation?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

here is the attached img what I want

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXsre.jpg)

anyone knows who I can do this in owl carousel v1.3.3 or even in its latest beta version if its not possible in v1.3.3. I need to show preview of next or previous slide as hover on owl navigation next of previous arrows.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/yunusga/EGrGN/. It sets images for bullets. You can do the same for arrows.

Comment: I tried that already but it does not work. I need to show thumbnail of the next slide on hover of owl arrows.

Comment: Maybe if you let 2 items in the carousel and the second one is small, in the right with z-index smaller than the z-index of the arrow, you will obtain that effect you need. What you think?

Comment: what about the previous slide? I think some how I need to append next and previous slide with owl nav... like in the 1st jsfddle. but make in more dynamic. somehow get the url of previous and next silde's img and append it to owl-next and owl-prev..

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can let 3 items in the carousel and the first one and the last one can be small, in the left / right with z-index smaller than the z-index of the arrow, you will obtain that effect you need. What you think?

If this doesn't work, please consider to use [this](https://codyhouse.co/demo/clipped-svg-slider/diamond.html) , explained [here](https://codyhouse.co/gem/clipped-svg-slider/)  or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yunusga/EGrGN/).

If you use the link from jsfiddle, please check the function from there,

```
        // i - counter
        // Give some styles and set background image for pagination item
        .css({
            'background': 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ') center center no-repeat',
            '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
            '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
            '-o-background-size': 'cover',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        })
        // set Custom Event for pagination item
        .click(function () {
            owl.trigger('owl.goTo', i);
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, clipped SVG slider worked for me. I was really looking for this. Many thanks